# Outdated rosewell adapter driver

Tags: installation, 13.04, wireless, bash

Someone suggested that [this error](http://pastebin.com/gcW0LqTG) when running the install.sh script for my roswell network adapter RnX-N180UBE was caused by these drivers not being compatible with ubuntu 13.04, is this the case, and if so, what can I do about it?

```
    Authentication requested [root] for make driver:
make ARCH=x86_64 CROSS_COMPILE= -C /lib/modules/3.8.0-31-generic/build M=/home/user/Desktop/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105  modules
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.8.0-31-generic'
  CC [M]  /home/user/Desktop/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/core/rtw_cmd.o
In file included from /home/user/Desktop/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/core/rtw_cmd.c:23:0:
/home/user/Desktop/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/osdep_service.h: In function ‘thread_enter’:
/home/user/Desktop/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/osdep_service.h:575:2: error: implicit declaration of function ‘daemonize’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
In file included from /home/user/Desktop/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/drv_types.h:69:0,
                 from /home/user/Desktop/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/core/rtw_cmd.c:24:
/home/user/Desktop/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/rtw_recv.h: In function ‘rxmem_to_recvframe’:
/home/user/Desktop/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/rtw_recv.h:626:30: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
/home/user/Desktop/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/include/rtw_recv.h:626:9: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
make[2]: *** [/home/user/Desktop/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105/core/rtw_cmd.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/user/Desktop/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.8.0-31-generic'
make: *** [modules] Error 2
```

Comment: That script was made in the 2011, of course is not gonna work. I would recomend going to the sources and trying to get an updated version.

Comment: What is your wireless device from the command: lsusb

Comment: Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8191SU 802.11n WLAN Adapter
The wireless adapter seems to be working, but I'm only getting about .5 mbs (download speed) when running ubuntu, but I'm getting 20-30 mbps when running windows, so I assumed the drivers needed to be updated

Answer (score 0):

I believe your device uses the driver r8712u; please confirm here:

```
lsmod
```

You might try a driver parameter:

```
sudo modprobe -r r8712u
sudo modprobe r8712u ht_enable=0
```

If it helps, write a file to make it persistent:

```
sudo -i
echo "options r8712u ht_enable=0" > /etc/modprobe.d/r8712u.conf
exit
```

If it doesn't help, there are other options to try. You may wish to check for any clues here:

```
dmesg | grep -e wlan -e r8712u
```

You might also experiment with N speeds disabled in the router.

Comment: Doesn't seem like it helped very much unfortunately, still under 1 mbps, also on a side note, even when running ubuntu I get aprox 6.5 mbps upload speed

Comment: Please see my edit above.